# How to display a specific word in php?

Tags: php, html

I need to display specific string with php, 
For example:

```
<?php
$text = "the grass is green"
echo $text;
?>
```

The output will be `the grass is green`, but how to display just `grass` instead of `the grass is green` ?

Comment: What is your aim? The request is a bit too vague.

Comment: replace `$text = "the grass is green"` with `$text = "grass"` ...

Comment: The problem is there are many ways to accomplish what OP is trying to. But the request doesn't mark a specific way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the specified word is known to you beforehand, then something like this will do the trick:

```
$word = 'green'; // you know your keyword
$text = "the grass is green" // your phrase
$a = explode(" ", $text); // create array of all words in $text
foreach ($a as $b) // loop through array
{
    if ($b==$word) // if match is found, echo it
    { 
    echo $b; 
    break;
    }
}
```

If on the other hand, your word is always in a specified position, then something like this will help you:

```
$wordPosition = 2; // you know your keyword place in phrase
$text = "the grass is green" // your phrase
$a = explode(" ", $text); // create array of all words in $text
echo $a[$wordPosition]; // echo the specified word, by position
```

Comment: ok !! thanks a lot sir, your answer is what i wanted :-)

Answer (score 1):

use string functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

In your case

```
echo substr($text,14);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text = "grass"
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get specified string using like this of one way.

$text = "the grass is green";

$textArray = explode(' ',$text);

echo $name = $textArray[1];

Output: grass

enjoy....